# Speeding up google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script running on my google sheets file:

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
 var num1 = ss.getRange("F12").getValue(); 
 var num2 = ss.getRange("E12").getValue();
 ss.getRange("E12").setValue(num1+num2); 
 ss.getRange("F12").clear();
}
function addColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var len = ss.getLastRow();
  for(var i = 11 ; i < len +1  ; i++){
    var num1 = ss.getRange("F"+i).getValue(); 
    var num2 = ss.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
    ss.getRange("E"+i).setValue(num1+num2); 
    ss.getRange("F"+i).clear(); 
  }
}
```

I have about 17k rows. Its taken too long to process the files.

Is there a way to speeding up the script?

Thanks

Im not much of an expert in this area so it was code I found online.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do all your work in arrays if possible.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const [num2,num1] =sh.getRange("E12:F12").getValues().flat()
  sh.getRange("E12:F12").setValues([[num1 + num2,""]])
}

function addColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var vs = sh.getRange(11, 5, sh.getLastRow() - 10, 2).getValues();
  let os = vs.map(r => [r[0]+r[1],""]);
  sh.getRange(11, 5, os.length, os[0].length).setValues(os);
}
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. Thanks a mill!

Comment: @TrevorNally Consider accepting the answer by clicking  the checkmark button on the left of this post.